# d3.js - Get the return text to print the whole key-value and not one letter at a time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a number of charts that are generated in a forEach loop. I have slowly managed to get most of it automated so that I can get as many charts as I want from a set of data with comparatively few lines of code.

The missing part right now was getting a title to the charts so that I could more easily distinguish between the charts and tried to use the key's value that I got from d3.js' nest-functionality.

My problem, which I haven't managed to get my head around, is how to get the return function to just print the title in one piece of text instead of iterating one letter at a time and placing the letters on top of each other:

An example of the "oneExport"-object: 
*{key: "Engine A", values: Array(126)}*

The code for the title:

```
            //Title
            myChart.selectAll('.title')
                  .data(oneExport.key)
                  .enter()
                  .append('g')
                  .attr('class', 'title')
            .append("text")
                .attr("x", (width / 2))             
                .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
                .style("font-size", "16px") 
                .text(function(d) {return d});
```

Am I going for the completely wrong approach or is there just some small piece missing in my logic?

Comment: Bit of a guess but what about trying `.data([oneExport.key])`? It sounds a bit like it's treating your string as an 'array' of letters.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. It worked, thanks! :D